# Consulta SQL usando JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito hacer una consulta que me muestre solo los fabricantes que no tienen ningun producto asociado a ellos usando RIGHT O LEFT JOIN. Hasta el momento solo he conseguido mostrar los que si tienen productos asociados pero no se como modificar la consulta para el caso contrario ya que en la parte despues del ON te pide que coincidan campos. He probado usando != pero no me funciona. Muestro las tablas.

Actual código que falla:

```
SELECT fabricante.nombre, fabricante.codigo 
FROM fabricante 
RIGHT JOIN producto ON fabricante.codigo != producto.codigo_fabricante;
```

Tabla fabricantes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes mostrar exactamente la query que te falla?

Comment: SELECT fabricante.nombre, fabricante.codigo
FROM fabricante
RIGHT JOIN producto ON fabricante.codigo != producto.codigo_fabricante;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar de está forma

**Opción 1**

```
SELECT fabricante.nombre, 
       fabricante.codigo
FROM fabricante
LEFT JOIN producto ON fabricante.codigo = producto.fabricante_codigo
WHERE producto.fabricante_codigo IS NULL;
```

- Usamos `LEFT join` para en primer instancia obtener tanto proveedores con producto asociado y aquellos que no tienen, pues está instrucción trae los registros de la tabla de la izquierda que existen relacionados con al menos un registro de la tabla de la derecha y además aquellos registros de la izquierda que no existen relacionados con alguna fila de la tabla de la derecha
- Posterior para filtrar por aquellos que no tienen producto asociado indicamos en el `WHERE` la condición
- Establecemos en la condición que la columna de llave foránea sea igual a `NULL` ya que esta misma columna es la cual sirve de vinculación entre ambas; entonces el hecho de que sea nula indica que alguno o varios de los fabricantes no tienen todavía product5os registrados

**Opción 2**

- Puedes hacer uso de `WHERE NOT EXISTS` Para buscar aquellos registros que NO satisfagan la relación que tú delimites dentro de la subconsulta así
- La condición `WHERE NOT EXISTS` devolverá false

Consulta

```
SELECT fabricante.nombre, fabricante.codigo
 FROM fabricante WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT producto.fabricante_codigo 
                                    FROM producto 
                                    WHERE fabricante.codigo = producto.fabricante_codigo);
```

**Referencias**

- [WHERE NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: Si, esto me ha servido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

esto no es lo mejor pero sospecho que te va a funcionar:

recapitulemos, has conseguido mostrar los que sí están, y quieres los que no están, me equivoco?

entonces la query es sencilla:

```
SELECT whateverfield FROM table WHERE thisvalue NOT IN (whatyouvegot);
```

`whatyouvegot` es los valores que ya tienes, es decir, `select xx from table ....`

Ten en cuenta, que thisvalue es un único campo, por lo tanto, whatyouvegot, tiene que sacar solo ese único campo, si por el contrario tienes dos valores, value1 y value2 entonces, where value1 not in (select value1 from table....) and value2 not in (...).

Esta construcción se basa en los siguiente:

ejemplo: tengo una serie de ids en una tabla, y quiero sacar solo ciertos campos cuando su correspondiente id pertenezca a un conjunto.

`select value1 from table where id in (1,5, 6)`, entonces me mostrará value1 cuando id sea ni 1, ni 5, ni 6.

Si quiero aquellos value1 donde id NO sea ni 1 ni 5 ni 6, entonces `select value1 from table where id  not in (1,5,6);`

si 1,5,6 son resultados de una query, sustituyo 1,5,6, por la query

Comment: He formulado la siguiente consulta con tus indicaciones pero me da error. SELECT fabricante.nombre, fabricante.codigo
FROM fabricante
WHERE codigo NOT IN (SELECT fabricante.nombre, fabricante.codigo
FROM fabricante
RIGHT JOIN producto ON fabricante.codigo = producto.codigo_fabricante);

Comment: qué error te da?

Comment: prueba, ...in (select fabricante.codigo from fabricante...), tu error es que where codigo not in select nombre, codigo...) es decir, comparas codigo con el valor entre parentesis, pero no tienes valores de codigo sino codigo y nombre, con lo cual no quiere comparar, tienes que quitar nombre, si quieres eliminar nombre, entonces añade otra condicion mediante AND